# Jquery remove text from second child div

Tags: jquery

I would like to remove the Paktutorial text using jquery. But I am unable to get the text replaced. The second div has a name dynamically created.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var text= $('#frei_user_brand').text().replace("Paktutorial", "Good News");
    $('#frei_user_brand').text(text);
});

<div id="frei_user_brand" class="frei_user_brand">
    <div id="frei" class="frei" style="height: 18px; ">Sample Text</div>
    <div id="big696power" class="big899power">
        <font size="1"> 
        <a href="http://paktutorial.com" target="_blank">Paktutorial</a>
        </font>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also target an element based on attriutes : `$('a[href="http://paktutorial.com"]').text('Good News');`

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  var text= $('#frei_user_brand a').text().replace("Paktutorial", "Good News");
  $('#frei_user_brand a').text(text);​
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zdGf4/)

Comment: I got it working on the sample page with just a single div. but the web page where I actually want to replace, it gives me empty value in case I prompt an alert for value of text that means it not working.

Comment: update your question with more information. provide original html or your page link

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#frei_user_brand a').text("Good News");
});
​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this

```
 var text=   $('#big696power').children().children('a').text().replace("Paktutorial","pippo")  ;
```

Inside the $(), you can put also the code which generates the name of the div, for example

```
var text= $('#<?php echo $div;?>?').children().children('a').text().replace("Paktutorial","pippo")  ;
```

which I use frequently.

If you know that the href will not change inside the  you can also use the other suggestion, by letting js to search the element by using filter:

Search with exact match:

```
$(E[A=B])
```

or
Search with partial match:

```
$(E[A^=B])
```

where E is the element in the DOM or the selector (a, input, div,...), A is the property (href, name, value,...) and B is the value.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. A small question for you I want to search a div starting with class name starting with "big" and deleting or replacing the content inside it. I want to do a partial match  and delete the anchor and other tags inside that div.

Comment: There're many "partial match" expressions in jQuery. That I wrote means "any property A which starts with B". Once you select the right div, you can do whatever you want. Just use the chaining method.